# Force network credentials

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to force Windows 7 to ask for network credentials after a specified amount of time?  It will ask for the credentials on my networked drives after a reboot, but even if idle for days, it still remembers the credentials.  I worry about this older version of Windows being secure, so I want to limit it's access to network shares.

Comment: @John - Ridiculous, this wasn’t possible, when Windows 7 was supported.  Even if it were possible, answer should be submitted, instead of just a comment saying “Windows has been out of support for years”. Which is dubious at best since extended support ended in January 23.

Comment: Apologies.  It has been a bad day for me here.